# Dismissing Lewis

Tags: humor, chemistry

If I were to take a benzene molecule:

[image: Benzene Molecule]

And throw physics out the door, replacing the carbon atoms with iron,

**What would it be called now?**

Hint:

> There's a great view from the hydrogen atoms!

Credits: SPOILER ALERT, ANSWER WITHIN

> [www.chemistryjokes.com](http://www.chemistryjokes.com/jokes/what-do-chemists-call-a-benzene-ring-with-iron-atoms-replacing-the-carbon-atoms/)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a puzzle

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil It's puzzling... I'll modify it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be a joke rather than a puzzle.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Then why did you answer it?

Comment: @randal'thor I didn't know the answer when I commented but I still feel its not a puzzle

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Shouldn't both answer and VTC :-)

Comment: http://www.chemistryjokes.com/jokes/what-do-chemists-call-a-benzene-ring-with-iron-atoms-replacing-the-carbon-atoms/ At least say that it wasn't original

Comment: @bleh I couldnt remember it was my own, or someone else's creation. Thank you, ill efit the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> A ferrous wheel

Because

> It looks like a ferris wheel but with the iron atoms Fe. Ferrous means containing iron atoms.

Comment: Spot on, fast answer. How did you get it?

Comment: @TommyWoldt I realised I'd heard it before